# How do I get schemas from Perl's DBI?

Tags: perl, schema, dbi

I am using Perl [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI). I know that `$dbase->tables()` will return all the tables in the corresponding database. Likewise, I want to know the schemas available in the database. Is there any function available for that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you're looking for is: [DBI->table_info()](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI#table_info)

Call it like this:

```
my $sth = $dbh->table_info('', '%', '');
my $schemas = $dbh->selectcol_arrayref($sth, {Columns => [2]});
print "Schemas: ", join ', ', @$schemas;
```

Comment: I wrote a script based on this idea yesterday, but `DBI::ODBC` does not support `table_info`, and I need access to an `*.mdb`.

Comment: PS: it does support it when the first two arguments are undef!

Comment: DBD::ODBC certainly does support table_info. You need to read the ODBC spec for what you need to pass to table_info. You may also need the bug fix in 1.46_1 - see http://search.cpan.org/~mjevans/DBD-ODBC-1.46_2/Changes#1.46_1_2013-11-16

Answer (score 1):

This works.

Create a database:

```
echo 'create table foo (bar integer primary key, quux varchar(30));' | sqlite3 foobar.sqlite
```

Perl program to print schema:

```
use 5.010;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
use DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader qw();
DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader->naming('current');
DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader->use_namespaces(1);

my $dbi_dsn = 'dbi:SQLite:dbname=foobar.sqlite';
my ($dbi_user, $dbi_pass);
my $schema = DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader->connect(
    $dbi_dsn, $dbi_user, $dbi_pass, {'AutoCommit' => 1, 'RaiseError' => 1,}
);

for my $source_name ($schema->sources) {
    say "*** Source: $source_name";
    my $result_source = $schema->source($source_name);
    for my $column_name ($result_source->columns) {
        say "Column: $column_name";
        say Dumper $result_source->column_info($column_name);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
*** Source: Foo
Column: bar
$VAR1 = {
          'data_type' => 'integer',
          'is_auto_increment' => 1,
          'is_nullable' => 1
        };

Column: quux
$VAR1 = {
          'data_type' => 'varchar',
          'is_nullable' => 1,
          'size' => 30
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ODBC to an Oracle database, I had to use this variation on Uncle Arnie's answer:

```
my $table_info = $dbh->table_info(undef, '%', undef);
my $schemas    = $table_info->fetchall_arrayref([1]);

print "Schemas :\n",
      join( "\n", map {$_->[0]} @$schemas ), "\n";
```

Otherwise, `$schemas` would be undefined when trying to use `selectcol_arrayref($sth, ...)`.