# Perl object for representing and querying a mySQL table definition

Tags: mysql, perl, ddl

I don't know completely what I want, but surely someone has had the same need, and has solved it in a far better manner than I could:

I'm looking for some mechanism to extract the data definition of a mySQL table from the database and allow it to be queried for the list of columns and their definitions, as part of a routine to dynamically construct DML?  It would also be good to have the table parameters (e.g. ENGINE, INDEX, etc.) available, too.

Our databases aren't particularly advanced, and I certainly don't have an encyclopedic knowledge of SQL DDL, so what I came up with probably wouldn't be of much use to anyone else.  Is there something already out there in Perl - preferably object-oriented - to do this, at least for mySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DBI interface has a set of "Catalog Methods": http://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Catalog-Methods.

There is a similar StackOverflow question you can look at:  [How do I get schemas from Perl's DBI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903948/how-do-i-get-schemas-from-perls-dbi)

Comment: The DBI interface sounds like the best way for me to go - it appears to offer everything I need, and besides, I instinctively trust Tim Bunce.  :-)  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there's a Perl package SQL::Translator, part of a toolset called SQLFairy.  It parses SQL DDL from an SQL script or from a live database instance.  It supports several RDBMS, including MySQL.

Then it offers tools to do schema conversions, schema diffs, and a bunch of other cool stuff.

- http://metacpan.org/pod/SQL::Translator
- http://sqlfairy.sourceforge.net/

I found the docs are better than most Perl projects, but still I had to read the code to understand how to use it in the way I wanted to.