# Retrieving available table types, schemas, and catalogs using DBI::ODBC->table_info()

Tags: sql, perl, odbc, dbi

According to the [table_info](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.628/DBI.pm#table_info) description, I should be able to call `table_info('%','','')` to retrieve available catalogs.  I should also be able to do a similar thing for table types and schemas.

When I do this directly through ODBC call `SQLTables("%","","","")` it works as expected, however using perl's DBI I just get back all available tables instead.

Is this functionality supported by DBI::ODBC? If it's not, is there another way I could retrieve the available schemas, table types, and catalogs?  This has to be data source agnostic, so it has to use ODBC.

Btw, I did read [How do I get schemas from Perl's DBI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903948/how-do-i-get-schemas-from-perls-dbi) but it wasn't helpful in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because DBD::ODBC doesn't in fact pass empty strings to SQLTypeInfo, it passes NULLs. I'd say that is a bug and worth posting on rt.cpan.org. However, as I'm the current maintainer I now know about it. By all means post a bug and if you come back to me I will send you a new version to test.

EDIT: The recent version of DBD::ODBC seems to do the right thing so what version are you using?

EDIT2: Bad day for me - DBD::ODBC is passing NULL when the strings are empty so go ahead and report it and I'll fix it.

Comment: See http://www.mail-archive.com/dbi-dev@perl.org/msg07271.html as I can fix your issue but not without creating a new one.

Comment: ok, it was a bug in DBD::ODBC and now fixed in github. New release will occur in the next week. By all means pester me if you don't see it soon.

Comment: I just released 1.44_2 development release with the fix.